# how to validate form in angular 2 having one input field?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-validation

I have `one` input field in which user can enter `email` as well as  `10 digit phone number` if any of this condition is fulfill i want to enable `continue` button . I am able to `enable` button when user type `email` but I fail to enable the button when user type `10 digit mobile number`

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5knn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-component%2Flogin-component.component.html

```
<div class="login_div">
  <form  #loginForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="email"
           autocomplete="off"
           placeholder="Enter the Email or Number"
           [(ngModel)]="userenterValue"
           required
           pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">
    <input type="submit" value="Continue"
           class="btn"
           [class.disbled]="!loginForm.valid"
           [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the pattern like this:

```
pattern="^(\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+)$|^(\d{10})$"
```

Comment: remove the forward slashes: `/` from the end and the begining